# angular 2 change position to fixed on scroll

Tags: css, angular, angular2-template

I have a left sidebar with position fixed. what I want to achieve is that when I scroll like about 50 or 60 pixel the position of the left sidebar should be changed to fixed.

**Left-sidebar.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'left-sidebar',
  templateUrl: 'left-sidebar.html',
  styleUrls: ['left-sidebar.scss']
})
export class LeftSideBarComponent {
}
```

**left-sidebar.html**

```
<div class="col-sm-2 left-nav">

</div>
```

**css**

```
.left-nav {
  position: absolute;
  background: #424242;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

How to change position of left sidebar from absolute to fixed on scroll?

Comment: If you dont want to code this yourself, ou you can take a look at a lib of mine that solves your problem: https://w11k.github.io/angular-sticky-things/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest you make use of the `@HostListner` decorator to listen to the scroll event just like this:

```
 import { Inject, HostListener } from "@angular/core";
 import { DOCUMENT } from "@angular/platform-browser";

     @Component({
         moduleId: module.id,
         selector: 'left-sidebar',
         templateUrl: 'left-sidebar.html',
         styleUrls: ['left-sidebar.scss']
     })

  export class LeftSideBarComponent {
         public fixed: boolean = false; 

         constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private doc: Document) {}

         @HostListener("window:scroll", [])
         onWindowScroll() {
            let num = this.doc.body.scrollTop;
            if ( num > 50 ) {
                this.fixed = true;
            }else if (this.fixed && num < 5) {
                this.fixed = false;
            }
         }
```

add the `.fixed` css to your scss file then in your template, you do the following:

```
<div class="col-sm-2 left-nav" [class.fixed]="fixed">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I found this : http://brianflove.com/2016/10/10/angular-2-window-scroll-event-using-hostlistener/

Comment: A passive event listener would be better (scroll jank), but @HostListener does not yet support this.

Comment: "document.scrollingElement.scrollTop" worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Angular 4 and that solution didn't worked out for me, I tried a different aproach, because num was returning 0 on scroll. ¯_(ツ)_/¯.

I hope this will work out for you as well.

```js
import { Inject, HostListener } from "@angular/core";
    @HostListener("window:scroll", ['$event'])
  onWindowScroll($event:any) {
    let top = window.scrollY;     
    if (top > 30) {
      this.fixed = true;
      console.log(top);
    } else if (this.fixed && top < 5) {
      this.fixed = false;
      console.log(top);
    }
  }
```

```css
.fixed {
  @extend .bg-white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" [class.fixed]="fixed">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div ngbDropdown class="dropdown custom-dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</a>
        <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
          <a class="dropdown-item">Action - 1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">Another Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">Something else is here</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```