# Lock a div when scrolling Angular2

Tags: html, css, angular, angular2-template, sticky

I'm trying keep a div at the top of the screen when I'm scrolling.

I found several guides and SO questions about it, but it's not working for me.

I worked with these :

- [angular2 scroll then fixed header in bootstrap full page modal issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42654351/angular2-scroll-then-fixed-header-in-bootstrap-full-page-modal-issue)
- http://brianflove.com/2016/10/10/angular-2-window-scroll-event-using-hostlistener/
- [angular 2 change position to fixed on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44144085/angular-2-change-position-to-fixed-on-scroll)
- [Angular 4 @HostListener Window scroll event strangely does not work in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44764592/angular-4-hostlistener-window-scroll-event-strangely-does-not-work-in-firefox)

And here's what I've done so far :

component :

```
import {DOCUMENT} from '@angular/platform-browser';
@Component({
    selector: 'example',
    templateUrl: './example.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./example.component.css'],
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
    public fixed: boolean = false;
    constructor( @Inject(DOCUMENT) private doc: Document) {}
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.onWindowScroll();
    }
    @HostListener('window:scroll', [])
    onWindowScroll() {
        let number = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || window.scrollY || 0;
        if (number > 100) {
            this.fixed = true;
        } else if (this.fixed && number < 10) {
            this.fixed = false;
        }
    }
}
```

html :

```
<body>
    <div [class.fixed]="fixed"> some content </div>
    <div> page content </div>
</body>
```

css :

```
.fixed{
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

I'm using Angular, which is up to date, with a node server and testing on Firefox.

And this doesn't work, with no error in console.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use position as sticky

Plunker Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/ouqElKKLehPYLexJdIxq?p=preview

```
.fixed{
        position: sticky;
        top:0;
        z-index: 999;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, I tried this, but it didn't work. I guess the problem is somewhere else. Thanks though.

Comment: Did you check plunker

Comment: Yes it works perfectly on the plunker you provided. But for some reasons that I don't get, it doesn't on my project.

Comment: Also remove class.fix from your div use plain classlike <div class="fixed"> some content </div>, you do not need hos listener also.

Comment: Alright, that was the problem. [class.fixed] didn't work as I expected. Using class="fixed" works totaly fine. Thanks again !